# Problems with lavalink discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to implement a music bot on my bot based on https://github.com/stuyy/Lavalink-Discordpy-Example with [lavalink](https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink) and [dicord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Before hosting it on [heroku](https://heroku.com/) I'm trying to run it on my computer but I'm having this error:

---

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grmap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 607, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\grmap\Desktop\discor-bot_py3.6\cogs\music.py", line 2, in <module>     
    import lavalink
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lavalink'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grmap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 95, in on_ready
    bot.load_extension('cogs.music')
  File "C:\Users\grmap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 664, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\grmap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 610, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.music' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lavalink'
```

---

These are the files on my project, the bot is using python 3.6.12. I'm using Anaconda to create a pipenv on Windows 10.

[image: Files on my project]

Here is what shows pip freeze:

```
aiohttp==3.6.2
appdirs==1.4.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.2.0
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.3
chardet==3.0.4
discord.py==1.5.0
distlib==0.3.0
filelock==3.0.12
idna==2.10
idna-ssl==1.1.0
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
importlib-resources==1.3.1
lavalink==3.1.2
multidict==4.7.6
pipenv==2018.11.26
pycparser==2.20
PyNaCl==1.3.0
six==1.14.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
virtualenv==20.0.10
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
wincertstore==0.2
yarl==1.6.0
zipp==3.1.0
```

I have installed on my computer lavalink but from some reason it doesn't work. Any idea of what it could be? Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT]**
I have had a similar problem with other python script and the problem is that I had installed python out of the anaconda environment, and for any reason when iIexecute the file instead of use the python environment version, it used the python installed on my computer, which was 3.7.2. @dzang was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to install the python bindings with `pip install lavalink` in the same environment you are using for the project.

Edit:

ok, so you need to understand how environments work. basically the problem here is that you installed `lavalink` in one environment but then you are using another environment to run your code. How do I see this?
Because in the error I read `C:\Users\grmap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37...` so this means that you are using an installation of Python that it's not the Anaconda installation.

In a terminal you can check what python you are using in windows by typing `where python`.

When you install something with `pip` you should make sure that you are using the `pip.exe` from the environment where you want to install the package, otherwise the interpreter will not find it.

With Anaconda you can create environment with `conda create -n myenv python=3.7`
and activate it with `conda activate myenv`
Then you can install your packages there. In PyCharm you will then need to select the correct environemnt interpreter.

I am not familiar with pyenv, but basically that's not needed if you use an anaconda enviroment. The concept is the same though, you need to activate an environment or directly point to the correct pip.exe, which in your case will be somewhere in `C:\Users\grmap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\`.

This is the thing, every environment has its own `python.exe` and `pip.exe` and set of packages.

Comment: I had installed it, i dont know if there is a way to show it

Comment: you can check what packages are installed with `pip freeze`.
Also, what do you see when in a terminal you run `python -c "import lavalink"`?

Comment: it's too long, but about lavalink it shows
lavalink==3.1.2

Comment: PS C:\Users\[...]\discor-bot_py3.6> py -c "import lavalink"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lavalink'

Comment: I'm using anaconda to create a pipenv on Windows 10

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try and i will comment what happened

Comment: I already have a conda envoriment called discord-bot,and it is acctivated and it is all installed I'm still trying to make it work

Comment: I'm using the pipenv shell the pip freeze shows that i have installed lavalink but when i run it it still odsn't work, do you need any mre information to know whats th issue??

Comment: did you use `pipenv install lavalink`?

I already told you what is the issue. The issue is that you installed lavalink in another environment, not your pipenv environment. That's it.
How are you running your script? you should run it with `pipenv run script.py`

Comment: or that you installed lavalink in your pipenv environment but are using another environment to run the script. So you need to figure out how to properly use environments. My suggestion is to use anaconda, create an environment, activate it, install the required packages and use that to run your script. This is simple and it will work. Otherwise go to https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and read the documentation and set up your pipenv environment properly.

Comment: what is the output of `where pip`? why do you say that the bot is using python 3.6 and then in your env path you have `Python37`?
what is the output of `where python`?
what does happen if you run the script with `python script.py`?

Comment: I've finally use another method, but for any reason it worked on the heroku.